# Request Response with PHP front-end and back-end

Tags: php, api, request, client-server, response

Currently, I have a client application sending requests (POST) to my local server. Basically a login form.

Now I would like for my local server, implemented in PHP, to send a response back to the client telling the client what errors were found...

Here is what I do to generate a response:

```
HttpResponse::setData('Incorrect Length for Password');
HttpResponse::send();
```

But nothing is in the response table in Chrome's debugger tools (Response) column.

I am able to successfully manipulate the header to redirect the user back to the login if there was no match within the database for said username and password combination:

```
header( 'Location: http://localhost:8080/iSchedj/index.php');
```

But this is all I can do... Just redirect... And I think this is not the way I am supposed to be redirecting. I feel that the client should be redirecting with respect to the response sent from the server to the client and have the client handle redirecting the user. I am quite new to web development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpResponse` is only available when using `pecl_http`. The default way to output content with php is to simply `echo` it. In rare occasions you might want to exit processing after some content, you could use `die` for that.

either:

```
echo 'Incorrect Length for Password');
```

or:

```
die('Incorrect Length for Password');
```

---

You also might want to add error reporting into your PHP file, preferably at the beginning:

```
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

This should only be considered for developing though.

Comment: I feel so dumb... durp durp durp... Thank you... But if I echo from the server side, how do I rerender the login page with lets say an alert?